# Stop/interrupt function execution which works with getTime

Tags: javascript

When I press middle mouse button it shows "after 1 sec" in console after one second. It's ok, it's what I need. But I also want to stop 1 sec delay if I release middle mouse button (mouseup listener). But now while 'wait' function executes 'mouseup' listener of course will not change 'delay' variable to false (only after 1 sec was passed). But mb is there any way I can do it? (to stop 'wait' function, e.g. when it delayed 0.5 sec on mouseup middle button, not 1 sec)

```
function wait(ms){
   var start = new Date().getTime();
   var end = start;
   while((end < start + ms) && delay == true) {
     end = new Date().getTime();
  }
}

var delay = false;

document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    if (e.button == 1) { // 1 - middle mouse button
        delay = true;
        wait(1000); // delay 1 sec
        console.log("after 1 sec");
    }
});

document.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
    if (e.button == 1) { 
        delay = false;
    }
});
```

**update:**
I'm going to replace `console.log("after 1 sec");` with `document.execCommand("copy");`, We can delay copy to clipboard maximum for 1 sec in Chrome browser using `setTimeout()` func, but it won't work in Firefox with `setTimeout()`, but `wait(999); document.execCommand('copy');` works for Firefox (999 ms maximum allowed)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the mousedown listener function will block further execution until it finishes. Your wait function implements so called "busy waiting". You should use `setTimeout()` which allows you to execute a function asynchronously after a specific time. You get a handle back from `setTimeout()` which you can use to abort the timeout if you release the mouse button. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout for more information.

Comment: I should have mentioned what I really want then. I'm going to replace `console.log("after 1 sec");` with `document.execCommand("copy");`, We can delay copy to clipboard maximum for 1 sec in Chrome browser using `setTimeout()` func, but it won't work in Firefox with `setTimeout()`, but `wait(999); document.execCommand('copy');` works for Firefox (999 ms maximum allowed).

Comment: Then there is no solution for you if you can not copy the clipboard from setTimeout(). Busy waiting will always block your mouseup event.